# Pass commands one by one in script?

Tags: bash

I have this executable `myExecutable` which goes something like:

```
Please enter username... 
(I enter my username)
Please enter passsword...
(I enter my password)
Ok, terminating
```

So I want to call this script from another bash script and provide all variables one by one. So my bash script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
./myExecutable
// what do I put here?
```

These arent exactly command line args, so how do I provide it to the executable?

Answer (score 0):

Use a here document

```
./myexecutable <<EOF
yourusername
yourpassword
EOF
```

Comment: It still asks me for the password.

Comment: Many programs read passwords from the terminal instead of standard input. You'll need to write an Expect script to control it.